# Unable to call access session variable

Tags: php, actionscript-3, session-variables

I have a flash app which captures image thorugh webcam and stores it in a file throught save.php (below). Now the problem I have is that I am unable to access my session variables when save.php is loaded. Is there a different method I need to use when calling session variables?

```
   <?php

   include 'session.php';
   sec_session_start();

   $userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];
   $w = 300;
   $h = 400;


   $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);


    imagefill($img, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

    $rows = 0;
    $cols = 0;

    for($rows = 0; $rows < $h; $rows++){

    $c_row = explode(",", $_POST['px' . $rows]);
       for($cols = 0; $cols < $w; $cols++){
            $value = $c_row[$cols];
            if($value != ""){
        $hex = $value;
        while(strlen($hex) < 6){
            $hex = "0" . $hex;
        }

        $r = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 2));
        $g = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 2));
        $b = hexdec(substr($hex, 4, 2));

        $test = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);

        imagesetpixel($img, $cols, $rows, $test);
        }
      }
    }

    if(isset($userid)){
    $fp = fopen("name.jpg", "w");
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($img, "", 90);
    $img = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    fwrite($fp, $img);
   echo "name.jpg";
    echo $userid;
   exit;
  }
?>
```

This session.php

```
      function sec_session_start() {
       $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; 
       $secure = true; 
        $httponly = true;

       ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
        $cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"],
              $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); 
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); 
       }
```

data is sent from flash to save.php through

```
     load_var.sendAndLoad("save.php", result_lv, "POST");
```

thank you for you time.

**UPDATE**

Ok now I am trying to pass the session variable to flash and retrieve it in save.php. This is how flsahvars are used.

```
      var flashvars = {
        phpsessionid:<?php print $user_id;?>,
       };

        var cam = new SWFObject("webcamvid.swf", "player_mc", "400", "500", "8",      
        "#336699",flashvars);
            cam.addParam("quality", "high");    
            cam.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
              cam.addParam("pluginurl", "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer");
           cam.addParam("pluginspage", "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer");
           <!--so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true"); -->
            cam.addParam("salign", "t");
           cam.write("takepic");
```

This is used to retrieve flashvars in flash app:

```
        function getFlashVars():Object {
          return Object( LoaderInfo( this.loaderInfo ).parameters );
           }
         var _var1=getFlashVars().phpsessionid;
```

And then send.

```
      _var1.sendAndLoad("save.php", PHPSESSNID, "POST");
```

Please note the flash also has

```
     load_var.sendAndLoad("save.php", result_lv, "POST");
```

which is another variable.

I am unable to retrieve the _var1 in save.php. Any idea how I can make this work Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the session ID with the request from the flash app. That is either setting the cookie or passing it in a field and you can then activate it with `session_id($ID_HERE);` and/or `$_COOKIE` before using session start.

Comment: Hmm while looking for the simplest solution first I noticed that there is an unmatched ) near $httponly. Is it suppose to be part of a function call that was accidentally deleted?

Comment: What's happening in session.php after the session_get_cookie_params() line? Is that valid syntax?

Comment: I have checked, I can call the variables in all other documents accept save.php. I cannot access session variables when this file is loaded through flash. If I just enter the url in address bar and access save.php the session variables are called. Any idea. ? thanks

Comment: Well if it works with php only then I assume that its flash thats dropping the ball.

Comment: is there work around to get flash send session ??

Comment: I do not program in flash but a quick google search brought this tutorial up: http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=39

Comment: thanx bro ... you r a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Add **session_start();** in the topmost part of your PHP code first !

```
<?php
session_start();

/*

your code

*/

?>
```

Comment: it is in sec_session_start() in session.php

Comment: Yep i have seen that already, many docs suggest that `session_start()` must be on the top-most hierrarchy next to ini configurations.

Answer (score 0):

ok so in this all you need to do is use session as following.

```
  function sec_session_start() {
   $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; 
   $secure = **flase;**
    $httponly = true;

   ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
    $cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"],
          $secure, $httponly); 
  session_name($session_name); 
   session_start(); // Start the php session
   session_regenerate_id(true); 
    }
```

call the session start function at very start of your file. double, triple and Quadruple check the code or any slightest error and you should be able to access your session variable.