# Work around to pass session variables between flash and php

Tags: php, flash, session, actionscript

Ok now I am trying to pass the session variable to flash and retrieve it in save.php. This is how flsahvars are used.

```
  var flashvars = {
    phpsessionid:<?php print $user_id;?>,
   };

    var cam = new SWFObject("webcamvid.swf", "player_mc", "400", "500", "8",      
    "#336699",flashvars);
        cam.addParam("quality", "high");    
        cam.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
          cam.addParam("pluginurl", "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer");
       cam.addParam("pluginspage", "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer");
       <!--so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true"); -->
        cam.addParam("salign", "t");
       cam.write("takepic");
```

This is used to retrieve flashvars in flash app:

```
    function getFlashVars():Object {
      return Object( LoaderInfo( this.loaderInfo ).parameters );
       }
     var _var1=getFlashVars().phpsessionid;
```

And then send.

```
  _var1.sendAndLoad("save.php", PHPSESSNID, "POST");
```

Please note the flash also has

```
 load_var.sendAndLoad("save.php", result_lv, "POST");
```

which is another variable.

I am unable to retrieve the _var1 in save.php. Any idea how I can make this work Thanks

Comment: Har someone asked this earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300641/unable-to-call-access-session-variable#comment23336779_16300641. This is the tutorial I pointed them to http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=39.

Comment: Yes, I have been doing this all day but not getting anywhere